# textreplacing using premade strings and a button in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace

```
<div class="Banner">

  <div class="container">
    <table><td>
      <h1 id="overskrift">myhead</h1>
       <p id="midtext">
         fillertext
       </p>
       <p id="sluttekst">
         morefiller
       </p>
    </td>
    <td>
     <img src="2.jpeg" id="billedSkift" height="200px"width="200px"></img>
    </td>
    </table></div>
     </div>
<center>
  <div class="container" >
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="toolbar">
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" id="changetxt" role="group" >Kuvertering</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" id="printbrev" role="group"  >Printbrevflet</a>
    </div>
    </div></center>

<script> $("#changetxt").on("click", function(){
     var oeverskrift = 'the new headline';
     var førstetext='the new text';
     var andentext='some more new text';
        document.getElementById('overskrift').innerHTML = oeverskrift;
        document.getElementById('midtekst').innerHTML = førstetext;
        document.getElementById('sluttekst').innerHTML = andentext;

    });
 </script>
```

I have used this method to change similar text in a testdocument however i seems to completely ignore the script here, i have tried several methods however none succesful even though the button is responsive.
ive run myself into a mindbogling corner any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You have a spelling mistake in your JS. In the HTML you have the id  as 'midtext' and in your jS youhave it as 'midtekst'. thats all

Comment: can you be somewhat more descriptive please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You have a small typo:

```
 document.getElementById('midtekst').innerHTML = førstetext; // typo 'midtekst' should be 'midtext'
```

2: Did you remember to embed jQuery above your JavaScript?

3: The `ø` in var `førstetext='the new text';` breaks it on my local machine in Chrome but not in Safari. The fiddle works in both browsers. Try removing the `ø`.

Comment: the typo were made while i was shortening the code down/translating for transparency's sake, however i have embedded the following related to jQuery earlier in the code:
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
i have also tried <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
without luck

Comment: Then Check this fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/ro9osevw/ Does this solve your problem?

Comment: my IDE must be broken because it works in the fiddle